# Find the most repeated sequence in a file

Tags: awk, grep

I have a file with some binary sequence [010101...], and I would like to get the most generated sequence of 5 bits in the file.

Example of my file:

```
00010111000100100100100100100101110101010100011001010111011100010
```

I've started by generating all the possible sequences, means if I take the first 7 bits, I will get the following sequences:

```
00010 00101 01011
```

Now I'm looking for a way the  count the occurrence of each sequence in the file.

Any help, please?

Comment: Are you doing this in C, cpp, java? Or do you want psuedo-code?

Comment: That does seem inefficient, counting every single possibility...

Comment: I'm doing it in Perl orTcl

Comment: not every single possibility, as I explain the first 7 bits will give 3 sequence on 5 bits each

Comment: You do it in Perl or Tcl, but tagged it awk and grep?

Comment: I'm scripting the main script in perl or tcl and I think that awk is more dedicated for such treatment correct me if i wrong

Comment: You are definitely wrong in calling awk from perl when perl is quite capable of doing it all by itself.

Comment: i was thinking of generating a file of sequence then using it to grep in the main file of sequences using grep -f

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using perl, you could go for something like this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $str = '00010111000100100100100100100101110101010100011001010111011100010';

# create list of all substrings of length 5
my @sequences = map { substr $str, $_, 5 } 0..length($str) - 5;

# build hash of counts for each substring
my %counts;
++$counts{$_} for @sequences;

# take key corresponding to the maximum value in counts
my ($max) = sort { $counts{$b} <=> $counts{$a} } keys %counts;

print "$max\n";
```

Output:

```
10010
```

Answer (score 2):

With `awk` and UNIX utils:

*count.awk*

```
{
    for(i=0;i<=length($0)-5;i++) {
        a[substr($0,i,5)]++
    }
}
END{for(i in a){print i, a[i]}}
```

Call it:

```
awk -f count.awk input.file | sort -k2
```

This gives you a sorted list of all 5 bit sequences. If you want just the most frequent, use:

```
awk -f count.awk input.file | sort -k2 | tail -n1 | cut -d' ' -f1
```

---

Btw, you can also use a single `awk` script but imo the combination of the above tools gives you more flexibility.

Just for completeness:

*count.awk*:

```
{
    for(i=0;i<=length($0)-5;i++){
        a[substr($0,i,5)]++
    }
}
END {
    for(i in a) {
        if(a[i]>=a[m] || !m) {
            m=i
        }
    }
    print m
}
```

Comment: Thank you hek2mgl for your help, I've used the first script it's work fine